# proof: Set of projections onto a k-dim subspace is closed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am struggling with the proof that the set of linear maps with P^2=P and fixed rank k is closed. My idea is proving that this is the intersection of the sets satisfying each condition. And the set of projections would be the preimage of 0 under the continuous function ( )^2-( ) and therefore closed. Is it even true that the set of linear maps of a fixed rank are closed?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is true.

For example,

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

are projections of rank 1. But their sum, $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

is a projection of rank 2.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Would it work if I do not no considering being closed under some operations, but closed as sets?

Comment: Can you expand by what you mean by closed as sets

Comment: It is a property of subsets in a topological space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set